# How do I specify a Maven property in a Gradle build script?

Tags: maven, gradle

I am migrating from Maven3 to Gradle and I have a transitive dependency on Spring in this form:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>${supported-spring-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I cannot change my dependent's pom.xml, so how can I resolve this transitive dependency? There are two issues here.

1. How do I declare a property in a manner that Gradle will use it for depencency resolution?
2. How do I declare a property that is invalid Gradle syntax (e.g., supported-spring-version)?

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1. Setting a Java system property (e.g. `System.setProperty("supported-spring-version", "3.0")`) in your Gradle build might do the job.

Ad 2. You don't declare this as a Groovy property.

Answer (score 0):

For detailed information take a look at: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

The syntax for declaring dependencies in gradle is as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '${supported-spring-version}'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

For setting the supported-spring-version property you can use a config.groovy file as described in this tutorial: 
http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/gradle-goodness-using-properties-for.html